# Meteor Sub/pub with reactive vars break the DDP push?

Tags: meteor, ddp

I try to use reactive vars to filter the published data, on a data list page, users can pickup 2 dates to show the data created during the dates; all works great until i got few computers to access this page at same time; the data changes would not push to every computers automatically- only the computer which makes the change has the new data listed. other computers have to refresh the page manually to see the new data or updated data.

if i remove the reactive vars in the sub/pub, all are good - if one computer changes the data, all computers get the new data immediately and automatically.
i even put the date filter to the helper - still same - no DDP push, same as in the sub/pub.
any ideas? any input are very appreciated.v

sub

```
Template.TestRV.onCreated(function () {
    this.startDate = new ReactiveVar({});
    this.endDate =new ReactiveVar({});
    var sDate = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 30));
    var eDate = new Date();
//show last 30 days data by default
    this.startDate.set(sDate);
    this.endDate.set(eDate);
     this.autorun(() => {
        this.subscribe('shipAllRV',this.startDate.get(),this.endDate.get());
     });

    //this.autorun(() => {
        //this.subscribe('shipAll');
    //});
});

Template.TestRV.helpers({
    testListRV: function () {
        let start = Template.instance().startDate.get();
        let end = Template.instance().endDate.get();
        return SHIP.find(
            {createdAt: { $lte: end, $gte: start }},
            { sort: { createdAt: -1 } }
        );
    },
    testList: function(){
        return SHIP.find({},{ sort: { createdAt:-1} });
    }
});
```

pub  -SHIP is my collection

```
Meteor.publish('shipAll', function() {
    return SHIP.find({});
});
Meteor.publish('shipAllRV', function(startDate,endDate) {
  return SHIP.find({createdAt:{$lte:endDate,$gte:startDate}},{ sort: { createdAt: -1 } });
});
```

BTW,
1. i tried session variable is same;
2. if i don’t update the createdAt field in my SHIP.update method, it seems all good even the reactive vars in sub/pub

how can i do it correctly? i need the date filter and DDP push. thanks

Robin

Comment: update - i put a session variable of order-Number into sub/pub, it works fine, DDP works fine when data added or updated;
it seems just can’t use date as reactive vars/session vars in sub/pub?

Comment: Would you please share the HTML code too?